# Get rid of orange edge around radio buttons

Tags: 14.04, application-development, gtk3

I am currently working on a GTK+ 3 program and I constantly encounter this rendering mistake. The edges around radio buttons are drawn orange which is especially visible when the window is passive and the buttons turn grey. Is this a Ubuntu-Bug or related to my computer?

[image]

### Follow the bug report

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1297302

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your current used theme, you can either (which is more likely and easy found out) edit/change/modify the graphics `.svg` or `.png`, like shown in the screen-shot below or by changing the color-coded values for visually drawn window graphics in the themes `.ccs` files.

1. Find out, what theme you are using.
2. Browse through the graphics folders (first) to find a visual match.
   To edit [.svg] files simply use [inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) and for [.png] files [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/). *<sub>Install via Software-Center</sub>
3. If it is not imaged-based, go for the .ccs files.
4. The path/dir to look for is:

> /usr/themes/YourTheme/

or

> ~/.themes/YourTheme/

---

**Please note:** Highlighted/focused buttons, tick-boxes etc.. are all rendered by the default theme itself!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have to look at that. Don't you think it is odd that Ubuntu would have such an obvious rendering mistake? I also see it in the radio buttons of the Update Mananger.

Comment: It might be a bug (at worst). Only further investigation into the matter will sheds some light on it. Guess though it can be resolved as suggested. GL!